How to send out BLE Beacons with Micro:bits?
I want to send out a BLE Beacon, but I am really lost on how to do so. I have multiple Micro:bit devices and thought it should be possible with those. I could not find that much about it online and everything i tried, did not work.
My goal is that I can see the beacon signal in the nrfConnect App just as other devices are listet. For Example, I would like to write a local name in the RAW Data of the Beacon, which then would get decoded by the App.
Is this even possible with the micro:bits, if so, how to do it? Code example would be super helpful!
If not, can I alternatively send a beacon with a USB Bluetooth Adapter?
Appreciate your help!
I tried writing little programs in micropython, but they did not work

Micropython on the BBC micro:bit is not capable of using BLE. It is on the device, and can be used through C/C++ code using the DAL, or in the Microsoft makecode editor. However the RAM it requires is around 12K, which means there is not enough memory left for the Micropython interpreter. You will have to switch to one of the languages I listed above to use BLE, or use the simpler radio protocol, to communicate between micro:bits.
